# How to get a launchd plist to diretly run a complex 1 line bash command?

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, plist

I have a somewhat complex bash command which includes some pipes and an if-then-else clause, not to mention calling system program (such as `grep`) with multiple parameters.

Is there a way to create a plist that launchd will load and run this complex command directly? (As opposed to having the plist reference a bash script file containing the complex command)

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. When setting up the `ProgramArguments` element, simply use `bash` as the first argument, `-c` as the second argument, then `[your commands]` (remembering to replace any XML entities, such as `>`, `&` and so on) as the third, like so:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>ls -1 | grep *.txt | echo &gt; allTextFiles</string>
</array>
```

Replace the third element of the array with your actual command.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure you don't want quotes around the command string, but that you do need to html-entity encode it (e.g. use `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of `>` and `<` for redirections).

Comment: @Gordon Davisson - you're certainly right about the quotes - they serve the same purpose as making it one element of the array. I'm pretty sure you're right about the XML entities, too. Good catch. I've edited my answer accordingly.